# Get the fields name that contain @Size annotation along with their max length

Tags: java, java-8, annotations, java-stream

I have this entity -

```
@Entity
public class Employee{
@Id
@NotNull
@Size(max=5)
private Integer employeeId;

@NotNull
@Size(max=40)
private String employeeName;

private Long employeeSalary;
}
```

I want to get the name of the fields along with their maximum length allowed.
That is, for above case the output should be like

```
employeeId - 5
employeeName - 40
```

I have created this following which returns the name of the fields that contain @Size

```
public boolean hasSize() {
        return Arrays.stream(this.getClass().getDeclaredFields())
                .anyMatch(field -> field.isAnnotationPresent(Size.class));
    }
public List<String> getSizeFields(){
        if(hasSize()) {
            Stream<Field> filter = Arrays.stream(this.getClass().getDeclaredFields())
                    .filter(field -> field.isAnnotationPresent(Size.class));
            return filter.map(obj -> obj.getName()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
```

Suggest me how can I get the max length of the fields as well.

Comment: Will the code snippet below help?
this.getClass().getDeclaredField("employeeId").getAnnotation(Size.class).max()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   Map<String, Integer> map = Stream.of(e.getClass().getDeclaredFields())
       .filter(f -> f.isAnnotationPresent(Size.class))
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(
           f -> f.getName(), 
           f -> f.getAnnotation(Size.class).max()));
```

Comment: I want the solution in key value pair, i.e I want to set the values in key-value manner

Comment: You can use Collectors.toMap(...) to group the records to a map.